# JQuery Ui Effects not working

Tags: jquery, effects

When I use `hide()` or `show()` they work - but When I use `effect()`, they don't, here is a little peace of code:

```
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and my Script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".palas").fadeIn(2000);
     /*$(".palas").click(function () {
          $(this).hide( "fold", 
                  {horizFirst: true }, 2000 );
    });*/
$(".palas").click(function () {
          $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Uncommented part is working well, the commented part is not, I Even tried more options that this.

Comment: jQuery UI 1.8 with jQuery 1.5? Why not use up-to-date versions? Try jQuery 1.8.3+ and jQuery UI 1.9.2.

Comment: What is the `.palas` element? Some elements (like `<tr>`) don't always animate well.

Comment: element is a normal styled `div`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change you jquery ui link from version 1.5 to version 1.8

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it worked, but not after the edit, before you edit, Just like
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Sure I know :-), But I needed 9 mins to Accept an answer